# Is "havening" pseudo-scientific or effective?

Tags: therapy

A [fairly recent answer here](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/20676/9769) offering havening as a therapy has only upvotes. But a quick internet search found a rather brief and contested [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havening) alleging havening is pseudo-scientific.

So what's the status of this technique/therapy in psychology? E.g are there meta-analyses showing that it's effective? And how is the quality of primary research assessed in this area? E.g. is the sub-field reasonably free of publication bias (which nowadays is also assessed in the better-off meta-analyses)?

Comment: I am not familiar with this technique, but reading about it now for first time, I am struck that this is almost exactly what Scientologists call ‘auditing’, where the e-meter device is supposedly used to measure responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I am not familiar with this therapy. There seems to be 251 hits on Scholar (excluding citations and patents) at the time of this writing with a search for "Havening Technique'. Of these 251, there seems to be one single journal article from [Gursimran *et al*. (2015)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Gursimran_Thandi/publication/284023276_Impact_of_a_Single-Session_of_Havening/links/564afeec08ae127ff98776be/Impact-of-a-Single-Session-of-Havening.pdf). The publisher of this 'journal', *i.e.* the *[Health Science Journal](http://www.hsj.gr/)* ([Insight Medical Publishing](http://imedpub.com/)) is listed on [Baell's list](https://beallslist.weebly.com/) and hence a suspected [predatory publisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predatory_open-access_publishing).

In all, this Havening technique can safely be considered as a technique that has not been described in the scientific literature.

<sub>I am deliberately leaving out the reference to the paper, as I regard it a source, not a reference</sub>